# Making some CSS modifications in a HAML file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am still new to all `HAML` and `CSS` and currentyly working on this part of a code:

```
  - my_provider_list.each do |provider|
    %li{ class: 'group_classes group-list-colspace', id: provider.name }
      = provider.name
      %span{class: 'group-list'}= provider.value
      %span{class: 'group-list'}= provider.specialty
```

So I borrowed from other parts of the code we had and got it to that point seen in the picture below

[image]

But I can't figure out how to make some space between the values it shows for specialty and the cost value

What do you suggest to add or modify to get that part fixed?

Here is the generate code with html space added:

```
<li class='group_classes group-list-colspace' id='Physician 2679'>
Physician 2679
<span class='group-list'>218395</span>
&nbsp;
<span class='group-list'>Pediatrics</span>
</li>
```

And the CSS for list items is just this:

```
.group-list {
  float:right;
}
```

Comment: If this is used elsewhere I'd also consider creating either a helper (meh) or a decorator.

Comment: Is there already a css file associated with this example?

Comment: @EricC : Yes I updated the question now and added the group-list class . But group-list-colspace has nothing other than a padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add some classes to the spans and increase the padding of one of them for example

```
- my_provider_list.each do |provider|
  %li{ class: 'group_classes group-list-colspace', id: provider.name }
    = provider.name
    %span{class: 'group-list-value group-list'}= provider.value
    %span{class: 'group-list-specialty group-list'}= provider.specialty
```

Then add some style padding to specialty

```
 .group-list-specialty {
   padding-left: 20px;
 }
```

spans by there very nature are inline and are meant to be used inside of block elements and not to default to having any space around them.  You can easily get around this with padding.

Likewise, if you are using rails consider putting the provider list into a separate partial

Answer (score 1):

just add a non breakable space between them:

```
  - my_provider_list.each do |provider|
    %li{ class: 'group_classes group-list-colspace', id: provider.name }
      = provider.name
      %span{class: 'group-list'}= provider.value
      &nbsp;
      %span{class: 'group-list'}= provider.specialty
```

Comment: Is that a valid HAML syntax?  Tried it but didn't change it.

Comment: you can always put simple text in HAML lines (see [HAML Ref.](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#plain_text) ). Probably there is one line missing in your example (the cost value after `provider.specialty`) so the `&nbsp;` is in the wrong place. Look at the produced HTML source.

Comment: Thanks for follow up... I updated my question with the generated source...after adding nbsp as you suggested.